# Transformation of xy to polar coordinates for double integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a double integral (region is rectangle)

0< y < 1     0< x <1

When transforming it into polar coordinate

I have two possible cases. 0< r < sec(k) and 0< r< csc(k)

For each case, how can I determine the boundary of k?

Comment: Most of the time, when integrating, preference is given to choosing the variables to integrate over to make writing the bounds easier rather than trying to make the integrand easier.  If your region is a rectangle, you should try to integrate in rectangular coordinates.  The reason why we will at times choose to integrate in polar coordinates is because when viewing the region on the graph with axes $\theta$ and $r$ (instead of our usual $x$-$y$ axes), it appears like a polygon (rectangle or otherwise).  What specific integrand do you have?  There is probably an easier way than polar.

Comment: The question is "transform into polar coordinates" that's why I am doing it this way .

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the integral as

> $$ I =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y) dxdy = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\sec(\theta)}f(r\cos \theta,r \sin \theta) rdrd\theta $$
>
> $$+ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\csc(\theta)}f(r\cos \theta,r \sin \theta) rdrd\theta , $$

with certain conditions on $f(x,y)$.

Comment: yes. That's right. But how can I figure out boundary of θ?

Comment: @user226741: Plot the region and see the bounds of the strip.

Comment: plot the region of secθ and cscθ?

Comment: @user226741: Plot the square $0\leq x \leq 1, 0\leq y \leq 1$ .

Comment: Yes But I don't see how to find out boundary of θ by just looking at the square

Comment: Just see the diagonal of the square from the origin to the point $(1,1)$.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: @user226741: If I had a scanner I would posted a picture which makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need a picture. This one is better with two pictures, I think.

[image]

The figure on the left shows one of the points along the side of the square
given by the polar equation $r = \sec \theta$.
The figure on the right shows a point given by $r = \csc \theta$.
The first formula works for all radial lines between the positive $x$-axis
and the dashed line through the corner of the square
(like the one shown in the left diagram);
the second formula works for all radial lines between the dashed line
and the positive $y$-axis.

Everything in the other answer (except for the formula in the integrand)
is illustrated here if you think about where to look for it, so I hope
that answer will now be easier to understand.
The bounds you need are the angle of the positive $x$-axis, the angle of the
dashed line, and the angle of the positive $y$-axis.